# php refusing to find ssh2_connect() function

Tags: php, apache, apache2, libssh2

Operating System used

```
Windows 7 - V 6.1
```

Apache installed

```
httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi
```

My httpd.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

LoadModule php5_module "X:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Version of php installed

```
php-5.3.16-Win32-VC9-x86.msi
```

I copied the php_ssh2.dll from php_ssh2-0.11.2-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip uncompressed

```
php_ssh2-0.11.2-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip
```

to

```
X:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_ssh2.dll
```

My php.ini

```
extension_dir="X:\Program Files\PHP\ext"

PHPIniDir "X:/Program Files/PHP"

[PHP_SSH2]
extension=php_ssh2.dll
```

Apache has been restarted after configuring php.ini with php_ssh2.dll and after copying the file php_ssh2.dll to extension_dir - error persists

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in X:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\index.php on line 4
```

code used to test

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 22);

if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX"))
  printf("CONNECTED");
else
  printf("ERROR");
?>
```

A test with phpinfo() displays the page perfectly in the browser because php was configured with the httpd.conf but the parameter extension_dir appears as

```
extension_dir C:\php C:\php
```

but this parameter was set to "X:\Program Files\PHP\ext"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your ini file do you see `ssh2.shell, ssh2.exec, ssh2.tunnel, ssh2.scp, ssh2.sftp` under `Registered PHP Streams` if not dll is not loaded. Apache restart may be?

Also I assume you had

```
PHPIniDir "X:/Program Files/PHP"
```

in `httpd.conf` not `php.ini`

Comment: Your observation is correct. This line was the problem. Thank you for your help too PoX. I really appreciate That.

Comment: I've been banned from asking questions...  `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /var/www/html/olevel/Class/O_Cron.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/olevel/Module/test.php(7): Ssh2_crontab_manager->__construct(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/olevel/Class/O_Cron.php on line 21` And here's the code `$this->connection = @ssh2_connect(DATABASE_HOST, SERVER_PORT);`

Answer (score 3):

Enable the corresponding .DLL file to the php.ini (or separate extensions conf if applicable) that is used by PHP: 
`extension=ssh2.dll` (remove an **;** if it happens to be in front of this line)

We can check if the SSH2 extension for PHP has been enabled by using the windows command line(This might need an apache restart): 
`php -m`
This will list out all the php extensions installed and you should see ssh2 in it.

You should now be able to use `ssh2_connect()`

Comment: I saw an error sent by the output of the command `php-m`. This is `syntax error, unexpected '" in X:\program Files\PGP\php.ini on line 35 `. Line 35 of my php.ini was: `PHPIniDir" X:\Program Files \PHP"`. I put a comment on that line, restarted apache and it worked.

I sincerely thank Raidenace your help - Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Will work for sure.

Run this to install ssh2:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
```

now run this command to check if ssh2 appended to array of extensions

```
php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());"
```

now code to move your files

```
public function movefolder() {



          $connection = ssh2_connect('xxx.xx.xx.xx', 22);

        $res = ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'xxxx', 'xxxx123');


          $res1 = ssh2_scp_send ($connection, '/home/user/public/upgrades/downloaded/abc.tar', '/home/xxx/public/abc.tar', 0644);


           echo $connection . '--' . $res. '--' .$res1;

        die;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download php_ssh2-0.11.2-5.3-vc9-x86.zip
2. Set extension in php.ini
3. Restart Wamp

This is for Wamp with Apache 5.3 and W32

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

in the php_ssh2-0.11.2-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip you have **2** dlls

1. php_ssh2.dll
2. libssh2.dll

the first go here
X:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_ssh2.dll
and the second go there 
X:\Program Files\PHP\libssh2.dll